# Scroll to top after refreshing UITableView crashes after third cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

In my refresh method I'm using the following code to scroll to top which is working fine, but when I scroll down after the third cell and hit refresh again it crashes the app with `error terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException`.

```
[TableView scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1, 1) animated:YES];
```

The `UITableView` has 7 dynamic cells. Do I need to add something to make it work for the whole tableview?

I searched on StackOverflow for a solution, but none of them solved my problem unfortunately.

Comment: Show the entiere error message.

Comment: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds for empty array'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x189516f50 0x195a201fc 0x1894184b0 0x1000984d0 0x18c628904 0x18c5c6db0 0x18c5c662c 0x18c4daff8 0x18c0cc258 0x18c0c6e20 0x18c0c6cd8 0x18c0c6560 0x18c0c6304 0x18c11cb84 0x18a417e74 0x1894c88e0 0x1894d6e90 0x1894d6df0 0x1894d5014 0x189415c20 0x18f0fdc0c 0x18c546fdc 0x10008cedc 0x196013aa0)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Comment: your datasource array is empty.check before reload .

Comment: Hmm, thats strange because the data source is not empty, the refresh method always works without the scroll to top function.

Comment: Do all of those arrays you initialise during `refresh` indeed contain objects when `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` is called?

Answer (score 0):

Your cellForRowAtIndexPath function tries to access an array object that it's beyond its bounds as the error says. I am guessing you have an array that is being updated with different objects and the size is not always the same or if it is the array is not always full of objects.

What I would suggest before doing something like this:

```
cell.myCellTitle.text = [yourArrayVariable objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

to accessing your data, check first the count of the array is greater than your indexPath.row that cellForRowAtIndexPath is trying to call.

```
if (yourArrayVariable.count > indexPath.row) {
cell.myCellTitle.text = [yourArrayVariable objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]
}
```

This way whenever you try to reload your tableView you will be sure at least the function won't go beyond the NSArray bounds.

And one more thing, you should be careful about when and where you are trying to define your array and how you are initializing it. If you reload the tableView every time that you hit refresh, then you are probably assigning some new data to the array and you should consider reloading after you are properly initialized the array with your data.

Perhaps some snippets would help to see what you do in viewDidLoad, your refresh action, and cellForRowAtIndexPath delegate. It will also help to see the nature of your app and what you are trying to do in that UITableView controller. Things like getting the data from remote server and using dispatch_queue_t and call your reload from                  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue().

Hit me in comment if you need more details and I will update this answer as you develop your question.

Have happy coding:)

Comment: add if (yourArrayVariable.count > indexPath.row) {
cell.myCellTitle.text = [yourArrayVariable objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]
} with the correct cell titles and array variable but still no success. I also put the full code in the answer...

Answer (score 0):

Here you go...

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NewsTbView.delegate = self;
    NewsTbView.dataSource = self;

    [self refresh]; 

}

-(void)refresh
{
    catName = @"All";
    self.imageArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    self.titleArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    self.descArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    self.dateArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    self.linkArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    self.categoryArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    self.categoryNewsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    self.imageCatArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    self.titleCatArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    self.descCatArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    self.dateCatArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    self.linkCatArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    // Create the request.
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[config getXmlWordPress]]];

    // Create url connection and fire request

    conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

    MBProgressHUD *hud = [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES];

    hud.mode = MBProgressHUDModeIndeterminate;
    hud.labelText = @"Verversen";
    hud.dimBackground = YES;

    [NewsTbView scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1, 1) animated:YES];

}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CellIndent";
    TableViewCellHome *cell = (TableViewCellHome *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    NSString *CellName;

    CellName = @"TableViewCellHome";


    if (cell == nil) {

        UIViewController *c = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:CellName bundle:nil];

        cell = (TableViewCellHome *)c.view;
    }


    cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = 0;


    [cell.txtDate setAlpha:0];
    [cell.txtTitle setAlpha:0];
    [cell.btnShare setAlpha:0];
    [cell.imgNews setAlpha:0];

    [UIView beginAnimations:@"CustomCellAnimation" context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0f];
    [cell.txtDate setAlpha:1];
    [cell.txtTitle setAlpha:1];
    //[cell.btnShare setAlpha:1];
    [cell.imgNews setAlpha:1];
    [UIView commitAnimations];



    if ([catName isEqualToString:@"All"]) {
        cell.txtTitle.text = [titleArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.txtDate.text = [dateArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [cell.imgNews setImage:[imageArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
        [cell.btnShare    addTarget:self
                             action:@selector(sharePost:)
                   forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        cell.btnShare.tag = indexPath.row;


    }
    else
    {
        cell.txtTitle.text = [titleCatArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.txtDate.text = [dateCatArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [cell.imgNews setImage:[imageCatArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
        [cell.btnShare    addTarget:self
                             action:@selector(sharePost:)
                   forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        cell.btnShare.tag = indexPath.row;

    }


    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Is that the solution of your issue? If not, please edit your question with that code (that we need to a better understanding of your issue).

Comment: Hi Larme, this was a reply on Maziyar as he asked for the full code. With this code I get the issue as mentioned above.

Comment: Hi @Jan, as Larme mentioned please remove this answer as it is not the answer to your question and edit your question as update. This way everyone can see your new updates and can have a better answer as your question is being developed. thanks.